# Azure pipeline build artifacts for previous builds

Tags: azure-devops

We have a .NET ASP Web form application. Currently we use TeamCity for the CI part. Deployment part is manual. We take the build artifact generated by TeamCity and deploy the artifact manually.

Now we will be using Azure DevOps for complete CICD process. During the POC we have been able to successfully build and deploy the application in IIS. I am new to the azure pipeline and doing POCs to learn it.

In TeamCity, against each build the generated build artifacts are available. So we can easily refer to any specific build and get the build artifact for that specific build. This is useful in case of rollback. We take the last successfully build artifacts and deploy the same in case of any error.

But in Azure is there any build artifacts repository where we can get the all the build artifacts for all the builds of that pipeline ? There is a section "Artifacts" but as per my knowledge this is for publishing as packages across feeds.

[image]

Now I have come across JFrog artifact repository https://jfrog.com/artifactory/. But no nothing about this. Need to go through.

Anyone can please let me know , in azure pipelines , where I can get all the build artifacts against all the builds in a pipeline. Is it available against each run in the pipeline or I need to configure it somehow ?

In any release failure , I need to rollback to the last successful deployed artifact version.

Thanks in advance for any guidance on this.

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT, Yes we are publishing the artifacts but now we will be using JFrog for artifact repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Artifacts is feed source for packages like nuget etc.

And build/pipeline artifact you can find in your build here (of course if you published them):

[image]

Here you have documentation about [publishing and downloading pipeline artifacts - newer and recommended approach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) and here [about build artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/build-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

In short what you needs is add this step:

```yaml
- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@0
  displayName: 'Publish pipeline artifacts'
  inputs:
    targetPath: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/
    archiveFilePatterns: '**/*.zip'
```

Of course if your pipeline output is a nuegt package you can publish it to Azure Artifacts.